# How do I install an R package under another name?

Tags: r, installation

I'm using R 3.4.1 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6. I have version 3.0 of package `asreml` installed under `/tools/bioinfo/app/R-3.4.1/lib64/R/library`.

```
> library(asreml)
Loading required package: lattice
Checking for license <redacted>

> .libPaths()
[1] "/tools/bioinfo/app/R-3.4.1/lib64/R/library"
```

Version 4 of that package has now come out, but we would like to compare the results of version 3 with version 4. To that end, we would like to have version4 installed on our system as `asreml4`. I have downloaded the *tar.gz file with the latest version, but if I do

```
R CMD INSTALL asreml_4.1.0.93.tar.gz
```

it installs it in the `asreml` folder, overwriting the old version. That's not what I want.

I've also tried to install it in another place, rename the folder to `asreml4`, and copy that folder to `/tools/bioinfo/app/R-3.4.1/lib64/R/library` and then tried to load it, but then it loads the wrong version:

```
> library(asreml, lib.loc="/tools/bioinfo/app/R-3.4.1/lib64/R/library/asreml4")
> packageVersion("asreml")
[1] ‘3.0.1’
```

So, how do I install it in an `asreml4`folder in such a way that I can call it with `library(asreml4)`?

Comment: Is `/tools/bioinfo/app/R-3.4.1/lib64/R/library/asreml4` the folder of the package, or is there a `asreml` folder within that? Because `lib.loc` needs to point to the library directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1) edit DESCRIPTION** Download the source, edit the DESCRIPTION file to have a different name and then build and install it.

**2) separate library** Alternately install the new version into a separate library and then use one of these to get the desired version:

```
library(asreml, lib = ...)
library(asreml)
```

**2a) .libPaths** A variation of this is to use `.libPaths(new)` to change the default library path, issue

```
library(asreml)
```

and then change it back.

**2b) dev_mode** An easy way to accomplish the library switching is to use `dev_mode()` without arguments (from the devtools package).  After the first `dev_mode()` command is issued the default library becomes ~/R-dev .  At that point install the new version of asrmel using an ordinary `install.packages` command without specifying `lib=` and it will be installed into ~/R-dev.  Loading it using `library` without specifying a library will cause it to look into ~/R-dev first.  Then test it out and finally when you are ready to switch back to the original library and original asreml issue `dev_mode()` again.  `dev_mode()` manipulates the default library paths so you can use `.libPaths()` without arguments at any time to check what the current default is.

```
library(devtools)
dev_mode() # ~/R-dev now default library
# ...
dev_mode() # restore usual default library
```

**3) changer** The changer package can be used to change the name of a package making all the changes needed to the source.  Use it to change the name of one of the versions and then both can be loaded.  See [Use function from a package but different versions simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017879/use-function-from-a-package-but-different-versions-simultaneously/75019428#75019428) for more discussion of changer.

Comment: Editing the DESCRIPTION file was enough for my use case. Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit where and how you have to edit the DESCRIPTION file? I tried this for a different fork of the openxlsx package, but withouth success so far, see this questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168063/using-two-versions-of-openxlsx-forks-in-same-file