# Is there a way to install two packages with the same name in R?

Tags: r, package, install.packages

There are two (rather obscure) R packages with the same name that I'd like to install. Note, not the function names (which all seem to be different), but the names of the packages themselves are identical. Ideally I'd like to be able to have both installed, and use functions from both in the same session/script. Is there a way to do this?

Note: Both are available via GitHub only as far as I can tell, meaning they have to be installed using devtools or remotes.

Comment: do you have the `tar.gz` source of one of the packages?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447227/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-under-another-name

Comment: Thanks, @G.Grothendieck. The answer about editing the DESCRIPTION file worked perfectly. I downloaded the source for one of the packages, changed the name in this file, and used RStudio's "Clean and rebuild," which installed it with the new name.