# Use function from a package but different versions simultaneously

Tags: r, r-package

I have a multiple versions of the same package `foo` (all with one function `bar`), that I all want to use in the same script.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988559/how-do-you-use-multiple-versions-of-the-same-r-package) question, I can load `v1` of the package with `library("foo", lib.loc = "pkgs/v1")`. But this loads all of the functions from the package.

Now I want to assign `foo::bar` from the version v1 to `bar_v1` and `foo::bar` from version v2 to `bar_v2` to call them independently. But I do not see the option to only load one function of the library given a lib location (eg a solution would be to specify a `lib.loc` in the function call `bar_v1 <- foo::bar`).

Is this possible in R?

### MWE

I have created a test package here [github.com/DavZim/testPkg](https://github.com/DavZim/testPkg/), which has one function `foo` which prints the package version (hard coded). The package has two [releases](https://github.com/DavZim/testPkg/releases), one for each version.

To get the tar.gz files of the package, you can use this

```
# Download Files from https://github.com/DavZim/testPkg
download.file("https://github.com/DavZim/testPkg/releases/download/v0.1.0/testPkg_0.1.0.tar.gz", "testPkg_0.1.0.tar.gz")
download.file("https://github.com/DavZim/testPkg/releases/download/v0.2.0/testPkg_0.2.0.tar.gz", "testPkg_0.2.0.tar.gz")
```

Then to setup the folder structure in the form of

```
pkgs/
  0.1.0/
    testPkg/
  0.2.0/
    testPkg/
```

I use

```
if (dir.exists("pkgs")) unlink("pkgs", recursive = TRUE)

dir.create("pkgs")
dir.create("pkgs/0.1.0")
dir.create("pkgs/0.2.0")

# install the packages locally
install.packages("testPkg_0.1.0.tar.gz", lib = "pkgs/0.1.0", repos = NULL)
install.packages("testPkg_0.2.0.tar.gz", lib = "pkgs/0.2.0", repos = NULL)
```

Now the question is what do I write in `myscript.R`?

Ideally I would have something like this

```
bar_v1 <- some_function(package = "testPkg", function = "foo", lib.loc = "pkgs/0.1.0")
bar_v2 <- some_function(package = "testPkg", function = "foo", lib.loc = "pkgs/0.2.0")

bar_v1() # calling testPkg::foo from lib.loc pkgs/0.1.0
#> [1] "Hello World from Version 0.1.0"

bar_v2() # calling testPkg::foo from lib.loc pkgs/0.2.0
#> [1] "Hello World from Version 0.2.0"
```

### Non-working Try

Playing around with it, I thought something like this might work.
But it doesn't...

```
lb <- .libPaths()

.libPaths("pkgs/0.1.0")
v1 <- testPkg::foo
v1()
#> [1] "Hello from 0.1.0"

.libPaths("pkgs/0.2.0")
v2 <- testPkg::foo
v2()
#> [1] "Hello from 0.1.0"

.libPaths(lb)

v1()
#> [1] "Hello from 0.1.0"
v2()
#> [1] "Hello from 0.1.0"   #! This should be 0.2.0!
```

Interestingly, if I swap around the versions to load 0.2.0 first then 0.1.0, I get this

```
lb <- .libPaths()

.libPaths("pkgs/0.2.0")
v1 <- testPkg::foo
v1()
#> [1] "Hello from 0.2.0"

.libPaths("pkgs/0.1.0")
v2 <- testPkg::foo
v2()
#> [1] "Hello from 0.2.0"

.libPaths(lb)

v1()
#> [1] "Hello from 0.2.0"
v2()
#> [1] "Hello from 0.2.0"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) Successive loads** Assume that we have source packages for testPkg in the current directory and they are named testPkg_0.1.0.tar.gz and testPkg_0.2.0.tar.gz.  Now create pkgs, pkgs/0.1.0 and pkgs/0.2.0 directories to act as release libraries and then install those source packages into those libraries.

Now assuming each has a function `foo` which does not depend on other objects in the package, load each package in turn, rename `foo`, and detach/unload the package.  Now both can be accessed under the new names.

```
dir.create("pkgs")
dir.create("pkgs/0.1.0")
dir.create("pkgs/0.2.0")

install.packages("testPkg_0.1.0.tar.gz", "pkgs/0.1.0", NULL)
install.packages("testPkg_0.2.0.tar.gz", "pkgs/0.2.0", NULL)

library("testPkg", lib.loc = "pkgs/0.1.0")
fooA <- foo
detach(unload = TRUE)

library("testPkg", lib.loc = "pkgs/0.2.0")
fooB <- foo
detach(unload = TRUE)

fooA
fooB
```

**2) Change package name** Another approach is to install one release normally and then for the other release download its source, change its name in the DESCRIPTION file and then install it under the new name.  Then both can be used.

Assuming testPkg_0.1.0.tar.gz and testPkg_0.2.0.tar.gz [source packages](https://github.com/DavZim/testPkg/releases) both have function `foo` and that the two tar.gz files are in current directory we can accomplish this as follows.  Note that changer will both change the DESCRIPTION file to use name testPkgTest and the directory name of the source package to the same.

```
library(changer)

install.packages("testPkg_0.1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL)

untar("testPkg_0.2.0.tar.gz")
changer("testPkg", "testPkgTest")
install.packages("testPkgTest", type = "source", repos = NULL)

testPkg::foo()
## [1] "Hello World from Version 0.1.0"
testPkgTest::foo()
## [1] "Hello World from Version 0.2.0"
```

### Old

**3) import** Below we suggested the import package but unfortunately, as was pointed out in the comments, the code below using this package does not actually work and imports the same package twice.  I have created an issue on the import github site.  https://github.com/rticulate/import/issues/74

---

Suppose we have source packages
mypkg_0.2.4.tar.gz and mypkg_0.2.5.tar.gz
in the current directory and that each has a function `myfun`.
Then this will create a library for each, install them into
the respective libraries and import `myfun` from each.  These will be located in A and B on the search path.

Note that the import package
should be installed but not loaded, i.e. no `library(import)`
statement should be used.  You may wish to read the documentation of the import package since variations of this are possible.

```
# use development version of import -- the CRAN version (1.3.0) has
# a bug in the .library= argument
devtools::install_github("rticulate/import")

dir.create("mypkglib")
dir.create("mypkglib/v0.2.4")
dir.create("mypkglib/v0.2.5")

install.packages("mypkg_0.2.4.tar.gz", "mypkglib/v0.2.4", NULL)
install.packages("mypkg_0.2.5.tar.gz", "mypkglib/v0.2.5", NULL)

import::from("mypkg", .library = "mypkglib/v0.2.4", .into = "A", myfun)
import::from("mypkg", .library = "mypkglib/v0.2.5", .into = "B", myfun)

search()
ls("A")
ls("B")

get("myfun", "A")
get("myfun", "B")
```

Another possibility is to put them both into imports (used by default) with different names

```
import::from("mypkg", .library = "mypkglib/v0.2.4", myfunA = myfun)
import::from("mypkg", .library = "mypkglib/v0.2.5", myfunB = myfun)

search()
ls("imports")
myfunA
myfunB
```

Comment: I tried that but it only returns the currently installed version of mypkglib. Similarly, if I have mypkglib not installed (but installed "locally" with your command), the import::from returns an error library not installed.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it on a different system but I got the same error.

Comment: This is a [reprex](https://gist.github.com/DavZim/9b5e1705c726346f5a50cdec1f61509f) of what I tried. [This is the testPkg](https://github.com/DavZim/testPkg) and these are the [releases](https://github.com/DavZim/testPkg/releases). Note that on the test system, there is no package testPkg installed other than whats in the reprex.

Comment: I can reproduce that now.  Seems like a bug in the `import` command's  `.library=` argument.  Either omit that argument and add the path using `.libPaths(path)` or else install the development version of the import package as now shown in the answer.

Comment: I tried the code with `import` version `1.3.0.9004` as well as with the `.libPaths()` changes, but still got only version 1. See also the updates of the [gist](https://gist.github.com/DavZim/9b5e1705c726346f5a50cdec1f61509f)

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this non-working.  Have created an issue on import github site. https://github.com/rticulate/import/issues/74

Comment: Have expanded solution (2).

Comment: I think until the import bug (?) is fixed, I am going with solution (2). Thanks for your time and expertise!